# Doesn't Matlab optimize the following?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a very long vector 1xr `v`, and a very long vector `w` 1xs, and a matrix `A` rxs, which is sparse (but very big in dimensions).

I was expecting the following to be optimized by Matlab so I won't run into trouble with memory:

```
 A./(v'*w)
```

but it seems like Matlab is actually trying to generate the full `v'*w` matrix, because I am running into out of memory issue. Is there a way to overcome this? Note that there is no need to calculate all `v'*w` because many values of `A` are `0`.

EDIT: If that were possible, one way to do it would be to do `A(find(A))./(v'*w)(find(A));`

but you can't select a subset of a matrix (`v'*w` in this case) without first calculating it and putting it in a variable.

Comment: You probably want to instead use [`spfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html) -- "Apply function to nonzero sparse matrix elements"

Comment: mmm... spfun might be a good lead, but I am not sure how to use it in this case. first, the evaluated function is unaware of the index of the matrix cell it is applied on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You could use `bsxfun`. This gives the same result as `A./(v'*w)` without generating the matrix `v.'*w`:

  ```
  bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@rdivide, A, v'), w)
  ```
- Another possibility: if you only want the nonzero values, use:

  ```
  [ii jj Anz] = find(A);
  Anz./v(ii)'./w(jj).'
  ```

  This gives a column vector corresponding to your `A(find(A))./(v'*w)(find(A))`, again without generating `v.'*w`. If you need the sparse matrix `A./(v'*w)` (instead if the column vector of its nonzero values), use `sparse(ii,jj,Anz./v(ii)'./w(jj).')`.

Comment: Another `rdivide` answer! Very nice. But the nonzero solution might be needed because of the memory problems, but then again you have rearranged the terms to address that I see.

Comment: @chappjc Yes, since I learned about `bsxfun` I tend to apply it to everything :-) I don't get your point about rearranging the terms

Comment: kloop has `(v'*w)` grouped, but you can handle them sequentially.  It's just the nature of the problem I didn't grasp at first glance. As a result, the answer is actually different from the reference by `5.8208e-11` in a test case I just tried... machine precision error accumulating, but still tiny.