# How to do the following calculation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I had the following question, which is similar:
[Doesn't Matlab optimize the following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735356/doesnt-matlab-optimize-the-following)

but this is one is a harder variant, and the solution suggested there does not work.

I have a very long matrix n x r V, and a very long matrix W n x s , and a matrix A rxs, which is sparse (but very big in dimensions).

I was expecting the following to be optimized by Matlab so I won't run into trouble with memory:

A./(V'*W)

but it seems like Matlab is actually trying to generate the full V'*W matrix, because I am running into Out of memory issue. Is there a way to overcome this? Note that there is no need to calculate all V'*W because many values of A are 0.

If that were possible, one way to do it would be to do A(find(A)) ./ (V'*W)(find(A));

but you can't select a subset of a matrix (V'*W in this case) without first calculating it and putting it in a variable.

(The main difference from the previous question: V and W are not just vectors, but matrices.)

Comment: Quick suggestion/test: Can you make V and W sparse matrices as well?

Comment: `V'*W` is r x r. `A` is r x s. You can't define `A./(V+*W)`. You need to change some sizes. Maybe `W` is n x s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735356/doesnt-matlab-optimize-the-following/19735803#19735803) to the previous question can be generalized to compute the nonzero values of `A./(V'*W)` as follows:

```
[ii jj Anz] = find(A);
result = arrayfun(@(n) Anz(n) / ( V(:,ii(n))'*W(:,jj(n)) ), 1:length(ii) );
```

This avoids computing the full matrix `V'*W`, because it only computes the needed entries of that matrix (i.e. those for which the corresponding entry of `A` is nonzero), one at a time. So memory use is kept low. As for speed, using `arrayfun` is usually slow, but if `A` has few nonzero values it should't take long.

Of course, you could then generate the sparse matrix `A./(V'*W)` as `sparse(ii,jj,result)`.

Comment: +1 Tenacity! As you say, `arrayfun` won't be as bad as it might seem at first glance because `A` is expected to be sparse.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks! A loop may even be slightly faster than `arrayfun`. But it feels like a Matlab answer with a loop is inferior in a way :-)